# PyQt4: nesting two elements into one cell

Tags: python, pyqt

I am completely new to PyQt4 and I am working on a user interface which contains a QGridLayout with one QLabel, one QLineEdit, one QCombobox and two QPushButton.

I have understood that the QGridLayout object is containing the elements as follows:

```
(0,0): QLabel
(1,0): QPushButton
(0,1): QLineEdit
(1,1): QComboBox
(1,2): QPushButton
```

A sample instruction to add one of these widgets to the GridLayout is the following (this is the case of the Combobox):

```
self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.comboBox, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

The result is the following:

[image: Output]

I would like to add two new elements (a QLineEdit and a QLabel) in the empty position (0,2). However I cannot add both there. So I would like to know, is there any way to "nest" the two elements into the same place (for example using some other parameters of the method .addWidget) or do I need to re-set all the other elements with new parameters?

Here is a sample output of what I would like to get:

[image: Sample Output]

**Code Sample** (adding the QLineEdit in the position 0,0):

```
self.label_1 = QtGui.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget_3)
self.label_1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_1"))
self.label_1.addWidget(self.label_1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```

**What I was able to do so far**:

```
self.OffsetCond = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget_3) 
self.OffsetCond.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("OffsetCond")) 
self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.OffsetCond, 0,2,1,1) 
self.OffsetCond.setMaximumSize(30, 20)
```

The problem with this method is that the QLineEdit stays on the left of the (0,2) cell (rather than on the right, that is where I would like to have it), and if I try to make the same into the same cell with the QLineEdit to write "Offset" on it, it will just overlap the QLineEdit.

Comment: Could you post an example of your code? Maybe someone can help you if you provide a starting point for testing and suggestions.

Comment: @xndrme , I added the part of the code I'm interested in modifying, the problem actually is that this is just a part of a huge user interface so I can't really post some executable code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want using a nested layout with `QGridLayout.addLayout`:

```
import PyQt4.QtGui as gui

app = gui.QApplication([])

w = gui.QWidget()

gl = gui.QGridLayout(w)

lab = gui.QLabel(text='Nom')
gl.addWidget(lab,0,0)

le = gui.QLineEdit(text='BarsCond')
gl.addWidget(le,0,1)

##########################

hl = gui.QHBoxLayout()
label_1 = gui.QLabel(text='Offset')
OffsetCond = gui.QLineEdit(text='-1') 
hl.addWidget(label_1)
hl.addWidget(OffsetCond)

gl.addLayout(hl,0,2)

############################

pb1 = gui.QPushButton(text='BarsC')
gl.addWidget(pb1,1,0)

cb = gui.QComboBox()
gl.addWidget(cb,1,1)

pb2 = gui.QPushButton(text='NBars')
gl.addWidget(pb2,1,2)

w.show()
app.exec_()
```